# how can i get all the values in a dropdown using select class

Tags: webdriver

how can i get all the values in a dropdown using select class.
I need to print those value also.
Can Any one help in this
Ihave used the below code but i am unable to print.

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElementByid("id"))

s.getAllSelectedOptions()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it'll return a list of `WebElements`, so you'll need to look inside the list elements.

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElementByid("id"));

List<WebElements> allSelectedOptions = s.getAllSelectedOptions();

for(WebElement webElement : allSelectedOptions) {
webElement.getText();
}
```

Note that since you've hardly explained your question and/or the language you are using, I've guessed it's Java.